# What needs to be configured for Heroku to handle templates based on CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, coffeescript

I have a create action that handles an AJAX request. On my development machine, a template named create.js.coffee is successfully processed to generate a javascript response. However, when I deploy to Heroku, the application complains that it can't find the template.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template /expenses/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
* "/app/app/views"
* "/app"
* "/"
):
```

It's clear that the coffee handler is not there to preprocess *.js.coffee template.

Can any one suggest how I can configure Heroku to recognize and process these templates?

**Note:** Heroku is successfully preprocessing my CoffeeScript files that are present in the asset pipeline.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? Am having the same problem on Heroku.  I tried adding the following to my gemfile:

`gem "coffeebeans", :git => git://github.com/marcelloma/coffeebeans.git", :ref => "7b106"`

That's a pull request to the coffeebeans gem to allow .js.coffee in views, which again worked locally but not on Heroku.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here is my solution, as posted on [Github](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/14).

---

I just ran into a problem where my `create.js.coffee` file was working in `development` but stopped working in `production` (on Heroku). The logs show that Rails isn't even looking for a coffee handler:

```
2011-10-14T08:26:29+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template page_blocks/create, application/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json], :locale=>[:nl, :nl]}. Searched in:
2011-10-14T08:26:29+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2011-10-14T08:26:29+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

This is the (important) part of my Gemfile:

```ruby
group :assets do
  gem "sass-rails", "~> 3.1.0"
  gem "coffee-rails", "~> 3.1.0"
  gem "uglifier"
  gem "compass", "~> 0.12.alpha"
end

# asset templates
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "haml"
```

Only after I moved `coffee-rails` outside of the `:assets` group, things started working. Perhaps it would be a good idea to somehow make this clear in the readme, and perhaps even ship Rails with the `coffee-rails` plugin being placed outside the `assets` group.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, not exactly sure why it's happening though.

Comment: I want to upvote everything on this page. This was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

I'm even later to the party, but I just had the same problem and there's a simple explanation:

The "assets" group of gems in the Gemfile are for development only. Heroku does not load these gems in production because it relies on its own stable versions for its Asset Pipeline.

If you're using a special gem that sounds like it's related to the asset pipeline but doesn't actually belong to a standard pipeline (e.g. the "coffeebeans" gem) you should keep that gem outside the "Assets" group.

I just tested this theory and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On heroku cedar you need to add bin to your path as per the very last section of this page [Rails 3.1+ Asset Pipeline on Heroku Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar/). "If you need to compile assets at runtime, you must add bin to your PATH to access the JavaScript runtime."

Comment: I need this capability as well, but when I checked my Heroku config, PATH is currently not set at all, rather than having multiple values as in the documentation you referenced. Do you know if that's normal and that setting a PATH which just has /bin on it will do the trick?