# POST/DELETE request on Rails looking for a view on Heroku where it shouldn't be. Working perfectly locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I have a list of users on the user index page in a Rails app, and the idea is that the user that's logged in can start a friendship with another user by clicking the "Start Friendship" button beside their name. This adds a record to the friendships table.

The process works perfectly when hosted locally. This uses SQLite (though I don't think it's a database problem) and the log looks like this:

```
Started POST "/friendships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-25 12:48:16 +0000
Processing by FriendshipsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"P5qQAuaSD1SNkgLDI6yQ2h9GhJjAub7l7On3+ZGBwiY=", "friendship"=>{"befriended_id"=>"16"}, "commit"=>"Start Friendship"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'eL_PfKhO9ZnYTxXTPo9UiQ' LIMIT 1
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "16"]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "friendships" ("befriended_id", "befriender_id", "confirmed", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["befriended_id", 1], ["befriender_id", 16], ["confirmed", false], ["created_at", Fri, 25 Jan 2013 12:48:16 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 25 Jan 2013 12:48:16 UTC +00:00]]
(1.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

However, when I do the same on the version of the app I have hosted on Heroku (using PostgreSQL), I get the infamous "We're sorry, but something went wrong(500)" error. Looking into the logs, it seems that it's looking for a view that isn't there, but I don't know why it's looking for it. Here are the logs:

```
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/friendships" for 79.97.21.43 at 2013-01-25 12:45:39 +0000
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/friendships host=meetflag.herokuapp.com fwd=79.97.21.43 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=135ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template friendships/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]: ):

--- (then there's the list of where it's looked) ---

2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by FriendshipsController#create as HTML
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"n+LI+Br3ahg5FxhNUm2u0b5YcqZGKpfeK7c3vJLkMyU=", "friendship"=>{"befriended_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Start Friendship"}
2013-01-25T12:45:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms
```

It doesn't even seem to be getting as far as the database. I've tried moving the coffee-rails gem out of assets into the main body of the Gemfile (as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464900/what-needs-to-be-configured-for-heroku-to-handle-templates-based-on-coffeescript)), don't have the haml gem at all (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366394/rails-heroku-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong?rq=1)) and my rake db stuff seems right (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017668/heroku-500-internal-server-error)).

The Friendships controller looks like this:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
    respond_to :html, :js

    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:friendship][:befriended_id])
        @user.start_friendship!(current_user)
        respond_with(@user, location: request.referer)
    end

    def destroy
        @user = Friendship.find(params[:id]).befriended
        current_user.end_friendship!(@user)
        respond_with(@user, location: request.referer)
    end

    def update
        @user = Friendship.find(params[:id]).befriended
        current_user.confirm_friendship!(@user)
        respond_with(@user, location: request.referer)
    end
end
```

Has anyone got any idea what might be going wrong and how to fix it? The rest of the application works fine!

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

**UPDATE**

Just to give an update - I installed PostgreSQL locally to make sure that it wasn't something to do with that. It wasn't. Even in production, it all works when hosted locally. As I say, I think the problem occurs in the fact that it isn't even getting to the database part.

**FURTHER UPDATE**

The problem seems to be that it is trying to render a view where there is no view to render. I have tried getting rid of the .js.erb files that were in /app/views/friendships/ to allow the buttons to use Ajax but that doesn't do any good (I'm happy enough to do without Ajax for now). I could put in an .html.erb view, but I don't want one (I just want it to return to the user index page)...though if I can't come up with any other solution, I may try it, just to see if it works.

PS I refactored the controller from earlier, so the new version is presented above.

Comment: can you try doing `rake heroku run assets:precompile` and see

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I've tried that, but it makes no difference - the behaviour is as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I've got it working, but, to my mind at least, there's no good reason that it works now and didn't before.

To get it to work, I enabled debug-level logging in the production.rb file, by putting the following lines in:

```
config.log_level = :debug
config.cache_classes = false                                                                                                                                                 
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

(be sure to change the `config.cache_classes = true` at the top of the file)

and threw some `puts` statements into the controller:

```
puts "Current user:" + current_user.name
puts "@user: " + @user.name
puts "Start Friendship called. Referrer: " + request.referer
```

(I was just trying to get some information out).

Amazingly it works. If anyone has any idea why this might be, please post it in here. I'm just delighted it does!

Comment: I have same problem with Play application, its working locally, but on heroku all non GET requests (POST,DELETE in my case) just fail returning 500 error :(