# When deploying to Heroku i get ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am deploying my active admin app to heroku and get this error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial admin/orders/form, active_admin/resource/form, active_admin/base/form, inherited_resources/base/form, application/form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :haml]}
```

I do not know much about heroku so I am asking here for some help. The error says I am missing the form partial for orders, but I have it in my folders and it works locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git add admin/orders/form active_admin/resource/form inherited_resources/base/form ..

git commit -m "missing partials"

git push heroku master
```

As your partials file are not pushed in heroku

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was trying to use a Coffeescript partial.  It worked fine in development, but not when deployed to Heroku.

The problem was that the coffee-rails gem needs to be moved outside of the assets group (its default location) in order to work on Heroku, as described at [What needs to be configured for Heroku to handle templates based on CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464900/what-needs-to-be-configured-for-heroku-to-handle-templates-based-on-coffeescript)

Since I found this StackOverflow question first when I was Googleing my error message, I thought I would post what I found.